# How to redirect to link (clicked in email) after user log in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I have a rails application where we send emails to user, which contains links of different pages in application , now if the user is not logged in ,he will be redirected to login page by devise gem and the email link which leads user to application disappears from browser bar and login page is shown with link http://localhost:3000/employee#/registration

Now how i can save the email link ( http://localhost:3000/employee#/my-department) parameters before the link disappear so after login i can write code to redirect user to that link.

Email link examples

- http://localhost:3000/employee#/my-department
- http://localhost:3000/employee#/my-colleagues
- http://localhost:3000/employee#/my-stats

I want to save the information like my-department , my-stats, etc and after successful login , i want to redirect to these pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to provide an answer that's just a link, but that's pretty much what you need here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Basically you need the referrer location. That gets stored prior to redirecting to the login page, then pulled again upon successful login.